# How is a multivariable function integrated

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area

I am unsure about how integration is handled in the context of area integrals. For example, $$ \int_0^1 \!\int_0^{y=x-1} \! (x-y) dydx $$

Does the inner integral evaluate to $ xy - \frac{1}{2}y^2$ or to $-\frac12(x-y)^2$ - or are they the same thing?

Indeed expanding out $\frac12(x-y)^2$ gives $xy -\frac12 y^2 - \frac12 x^2$ with the additional $\frac12 x^2$, which makes sense as $x$ is held as a constant in the inner integral.

This example is from a book wherein $\!\int_0^{y=x-1} \! (x-y)dy$ is evaluated to $[\frac12 (x - y)^2]$. However, in a later example  $\!\int_0^{y=x-1} \! (x^2-y^2)dy$ is evaluated to $[x^2y - \frac13y^3]$.

Why are they treated in different ways?

Answer (score 3):

Both $-\frac{1}{2}(x - y)^2$ and $(xy - \frac{1}{2}y^2)$ are anti-derivatives of $(x - y)$ with respect to $y$, so either one can be used to evaluate the inner integral.

Answer (score 0):

An anti-derivative of $(x-y)$ w.r.t. $y$ is $-\frac 1  2(x-y)^{2}$ so  the second answers you mentioned is right. The first one is also an anti-derivative.

Comment: The missing negative sign was a typo. I have amended it.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly.